# django-storage with s3-boto break browser cache

Tags: django, django-storage

I have a django project which use django-storage over s3-boto.

Problem is that every file that is located on S3 unable to cache because the url is changed from each call.

here are two calls generated by django-storage :

```
https://my.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/user_6/profile_pic/profile_profile_picture_thumbnail.jpg?Signature=HlVSayUIJj6dMyk%2F4KBtFlz0uJs%3D&Expires=1364418058&AWSAccessKeyId=[awsaccesskey]     
https://my.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/user_6/profile_pic/profile_profile_picture_thumbnail.jpg?Signature=xh2VxKys0pkq7yHpbJmH000wkwg%3D&Expires=1364418110&AWSAccessKeyId=[awsaccesskey]
```

As you can see the signature is different. What can I do so it wont break my browser cache ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does S3 (using with boto and django-storages) give signed url even for public files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777900/why-does-s3-using-with-boto-and-django-storages-give-signed-url-even-for-publi)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your settings, just add the following:

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

This will make sure that the URLs to the files are generated WITHOUT the extra parameters. Your URLs would look like:

```
https://my.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/user_6/profile_pic/profile_profile_picture_thumbnail.jpg
```

Comment: thanks ! but if I would like to set some of my URL secured ? how can I do it ?

Comment: @Nuno_147 : Sorry, I had made a mistake in the original answer. It should be AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Nuno_147 : By secure, do you mean you want to add the query string auth for only certain files? Or do u mean https?

Comment: what are the security implications of removing the querystring?

Comment: To add auth query string to some of the urls but not all create another storage instance and pass kwarg attr querystring_auth=False.

Comment: The purpose of the querystring signature is for secure/private access. This solution makes everything public. If you want private access to files, you need to leave this true and cache the generated url instead.

Answer (score 9):

When `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True` (which is the default), django will generate a **temporary url** *each time* we fetch the url.

### If you don't want to generate a temporary url:

Add `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False` to your settings.py

### If you still want a temporary url:

Temporary urls will be valid for `AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE` seconds (3600 by default). So **we can cache this temporary url** (as long as we don't cache it longer than it's valid). This way - we can return the same url for subsequent page requests, allowing the client browser to fetch from their cache.

**settings.py**

```
# We subclass the default storage engine to add some caching
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'project.storage.CachedS3Boto3Storage'
```

**project/storage.py**

```
import hashlib

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class CachedS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    """ adds caching for temporary urls """

    def url(self, name):
        # Add a prefix to avoid conflicts with any other apps
        key = hashlib.md5(f"CachedS3Boto3Storage_{name}".encode()).hexdigest()
        result = cache.get(key)
        if result:
            return result

        # No cached value exists, follow the usual logic
        result = super(CachedS3Boto3Storage, self).url(name)

        # Cache the result for 3/4 of the temp_url's lifetime.
        try:
            timeout = settings.AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE
        except:
            timeout = 3600
        timeout = int(timeout*.75)
        cache.set(key, result, timeout)

        return result
```

Comment: Getting the error "unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" from line 13 key = hashlib.md5....

Comment: Solved it by editing it to:
key = hashlib.md5(f"CachedS3Boto3Storage_{name}".encode()).hexdigest()

Answer (score 4):

Protect some file storage

Most of your media uploads – user avatars, for instance – you want to be public. But if you have some media that requires authentication before you can access it – say PDF resumes which are only accessible to members – then you don’t want S3BotoStorage’s default S3 ACL of public-read. Here we don’t have to subclass, because we can pass in an instance rather than refer to a class.

so first remove protection for all file fields in your settings and add cache control

```
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400',
}

# By default don't protect s3 urls and handle that in the model
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

Then make the file field you need protected to use your custom protected path

```
from django.db import models
import storages.backends.s3boto

protected_storage = storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage(
  acl='private',
  querystring_auth=True,
  querystring_expire=600, # 10 minutes, try to ensure people won't/can't share
)

class Profile(models.Model):
  resume = models.FileField(
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    help_text='PDF resume accessible only to members',
    storage=protected_storage,
  )
```

But you also need to use your normal storage when you are in dev, and you are usually using local storage so this is how i personally went about it

```
if settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE == 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage':
    protected_storage = FileSystemStorage()
    logger.debug('Using FileSystemStorage for resumes files')
else:
    protected_storage = S3BotoStorage(
        acl='private',
        querystring_auth=True,
        querystring_expire=86400,  # 24Hrs, expiration try to ensure people won't/can't share after 24Hrs
    )
    logger.debug('Using protected S3BotoStorage for resumes files')
```

REF: https://tartarus.org/james/diary/2013/07/18/fun-with-django-storage-backends

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to subclass the Boto S3 Storage Backend and override the url method.

#### /project/root/storage.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class S3Storage(S3BotoStorage):

    def url(self, name):
        name = self._clean_name(name)
        return '{0}{1}'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL, name)
```

#### /project/root/settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = 'https://my.s3.amazonaws.com/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'project.storage.S3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*******'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '********'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'your-bucket'
```

Just make sure your images are publicly readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about using signed urls but still want to cache them until they expire, just use django's built-in [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api):

```
from django.core.cache import cache

class MyModel(models.Model):
    #using django-storages with AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH=True
    media = models.FileField()

    @property
    def url(self):
        """
        Return signed url, re-using cached value if not expired.
        """
        #Refresh url if within n seconds of expiry to give clients
        #time to retrieve content from bucket.
        #Make sure AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE is sufficiently larger than n
        n = 30
        time_to_expiry = settings.AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE - n

        #Create a unique key for this instance's url in the cache
        key = '{0}{1}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.pk)

        url = cache.get(key)
        if not url:
            url = self.media.url    #refresh url via django-storages
            cache.set(key, url, time_to_expiry)

        return url
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line in your settings.py file will enable the caching for the image file.

```
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
        'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
    }
```

Comment: This makes the image request set a `CacheControl` header in the response. However, it doesn't help OP, because the URL is different every time. The browser never gets to use the cache, because it thinks it's a different resource that needs caching separately.

Answer (score 0):

[Aaron's answer is excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42912118/247696). I've updated the code to use `S3Storage`, the more modern way of doing it. In your settings, have something like this:

```
STORAGES = {
     "default": {
        "BACKEND": "myapp.storage.CachedS3Storage",
        "OPTIONS": {},
    },
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage",
    },     
}
```

Then in `myapp/storage.py`, have code like this:

```
from storages.backends.s3 import S3Storage
from django.core.cache import cache
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import hashlib


class CachedS3Storage(S3Storage):
    def url(self, name, parameters=None, expire=None):
        if expire is None:
            expire = self.querystring_expire

        # Add a prefix to avoid conflicts with other apps
        params = "?{}".format(urlencode(parameters)) if parameters else ""
        key = f"CachedS3Storage_{name}_{expire}_{params}"
        key = hashlib.md5(key.encode()).hexdigest()
        result = cache.get(key)
        if result is not None:
            return result

        # No cached value exists, follow the usual logic
        result = super().url(name, parameters=parameters, expire=expire)

        # Cache the result for 3/4 of the temp_url's lifetime.
        timeout = int(expire * 0.75)
        cache.set(key, result, timeout)

        return result
```