# Why does S3 (using with boto and django-storages) give signed url even for public files?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

This is strange. I have mix of public as well as private files. I want normal urls in public files, and signed urls in private files.

I tried to change `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH to False` as I see by default, it's True in django-storages.

But, when I change it, my private files url is not signed (thus not accessible).

May be I am missing something here. What can be solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` sets the default behavior, but you can override it when you create an instance of `S3BotoStorage`, by passing in an additional argument to the initializer:

```
S3BotoStorage(bucket="foo", querystring_auth=False)
```

So if you have one bucket private and another bucket public, you can set the `querystring_auth` argument appropriately and get your desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but I have single bucket with different dirs.

Comment: still no problem.
two seperate instances will do it

`S3BotoStorage(bucket="foo", location="bar", querystring_auth=False)``

Your separation of private/public is media/static, you can just set different instances as backends.

Answer (score 5):

put this in your `settings.py`

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

Comment: Setting `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` to `False` worked for me and looks pretty strait forward in the code (https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/1.5.0/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L214) for both python 2 and 3. I'm running these verstions: boto==2.42.0
django-storages==1.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get around this is to set AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN in your settings.
@see: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L478

(tested with boto==2.38.0 and django-storages-redux==1.3)

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate storage types for separate folders, directories and manage the access permission there.

With Django - create a file you can call "storage_aws.py" and add the following:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media/location2/public'
    default_acl = 'public-read'
    file_overwrite = False
    querystring_auth=False

class PrivateMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media/location1/private'
    default_acl = 'private'
    file_overwrite = False
    custom_domain = False
    querystring_auth=True
```

use default_acl to define the access (public or private)
use location to define location - (you can specify paths) like

```
location1 = 'media/location1/private'
location2 = 'media/location2/public'
```

*Note the querystring_auth=False or True

Then when you define your model, you can specify which location to use for which model

```
from django.db import models
from appname.storage_aws import PublicMediaStorage, PrivateMediaStorage


class Upload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=PublicMediaStorage())


class UploadPrivate(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
```

The private files will have query string while the public ones will not, as defined in the "storage_aws.py' file