# Django pipeline + Django storage + S3: query string nightmare

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage, django-pipeline

I'm using **django-pipeline** + **django-storage** and an **S3** backend, but I'm going crazy trying to load my static files properly using `{% static %}` tag.
I read and followed the pipeline docs: http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storages.html#using-with-other-storages

And I created the following mixed class:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin

from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass
```

in my production settings file I have:

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myapp.S3PipelineStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365*10)).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y 00:00:00 GMT')
}
STATIC_URL = 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

When I run collectstatic using these settings, all works as it should, but by using:

```
{% static 'path/file.xxx' %}
```

I get an URL containing the querystring auth, despite I set `False` in `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` and thus my static files are not loaded… By removing that querystring I can load them propaerly.
I also tryed to set "`querystring_auth = False`" in `myapp.S3PipelineStorage`, but it seems to being ignored :(

Why settings are not respected? What could be an effective solution to remove that qs? (I'm thinking about a custom filter to strip it away… but I hate to write such "patch") …and finally, in case I have to keep that authentication query string, why is not working? How can I debug this behavior?

**EDIT:
it works… it was a problem related with caching :|**

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777900/why-does-s3-using-with-boto-and-django-storages-give-signed-url-even-for-publi). Maybe this is matter of order (e.g. django-storages overrides your settings).
Maybe try to set per-bucket?

Comment: I already seen that answer, but honestly I'm unable to fix my problem… I mean, I'm not initializing an instance of S3BotoStorage by myself… so what should I do? (currently I tried also to import "storages" app after pipeline and to move AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH, but it's not working anyway)