# django & AWS S3 - network/performance cost difference on enabling pre-signed url

Tags: django, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, django-storage

Say, I have a django project with static files stored on Amazon S3 with `django-storage` as a custom storage.

Say, I have a static file called `style.css`.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777900/why-does-s3-using-with-boto-and-django-storages-give-signed-url-even-for-publi):

- By default, `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` is set to `True`, and the generated link will be as such : `https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/style.css?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxx&Signature=xxxx&Expires=1595823548`
- But if I set `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` to `False`, the generated link will be as such : `https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/style.css` (e.g. without accessId, signature, and expire)
- for public file, they said I should set this to `False`

If I get this correctly, this is what people call a "signed url".

Functionality-wise, both of these 2 options above will work exaclty as the same, despite the longer link on the first option.

My question are: performance-wise, does pre-signed url affect CPU/networking bandwith as much?

If I have a hundreds of public files that can be served without pre-signed url, does my server get the overhead (in terms of CPU and networking) if I insist to serve all of it with presigned url ?

Comment: If the files you are serving are public why would you add auth to them?

Comment: Yes, I know it sounds not right. But question-wise, does signing the url cost that much overhead? If there is little to no overhead, then why should I ommit the signing process (?).

Comment: You should omit the signing process because if you don't no one will be able to access your static files